# Ordering list by default using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sorting

I have a system that uses hibernate, and I have two ways of getting data form database, generic dao and custom queries. Now we want to order all results from queries by a label, for example: ENGLISH_NAME. 
Is there a way of doing this ordering without changing a lot of java code in so many different places?

**note:** I am using ICEFaces and the results we're fetching is displayed using List< SelectItem >

Comment: Adding an excerpt of your code that illustrates the approach may help in understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you order English_name In query itself. Using order by English names desc.plus you need to post some code.